# How do I make turtles move with ranked movement order based on an owned trait?

Tags: netlogo

I'm attempting to make turtles move based on their score (0-1 continuous scale) such that the lower the score the earlier the movement. Unfortunately I've completely failed on coming up with something that works. The code to make the turtles is:

```
breed[a]
breed[s]

turtles-own [score]
set population 100

to make_turtles
 create-s (population / 2)
    [set color blue
      set size 3
      setxy random max-pxcor random max-pycor
      set score random-normal 0.75 0.1
      if score > 1 [set score 0.9999999999]
      if score < 0.5 [set score 0.50000001]
      ]
create-a (population / 2)   
 [set color red
      set size 3
      setxy random max-pxcor random max-pycor
      set score random-normal 0.25 0.1
      if score < 0 [set score 0.00000000000001]
      if score > 0.5 [set score 0.499999999999]
      ]
end
```

and I have them moving properly, I just need them to move in order of their 'score'. Thanks in advance for any tips!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to sort the turtles by their score and iterate over the resulting list asking each turtle to move.

```
 foreach sort-on [score] turtles [ ask ? [ move]]
```

Comment: That did the trick! BUT it raised a new problem: I put the code in my go command and the turtles are moving in the right order, but now the code takes way too long to run (presumably because it's recalculating the movement order). Is there a way I can have the list made in to a list, maybe an agentset(?), in the setup command to reduce processing requirements?

Comment: You don't want to use an agentset because that'll remove the ordering. Instead, In your setup command assign a global variable to the result of the sort-on score. In your go command, say foreach <global-var-name> [ ask ? [move]]. That's only if the scores don't change overtime.

Comment: That definitely seemed to help, but it's still taking much longer to run the code than before. I'll try to optimize the rest and see what happens. Thanks!

Comment: I realized I was asking the question wrong. I reposted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38250139/assigning-turtles-a-ranked-number-in-netlogo

and provide a generic code example that can be modified to fit anyone's purposes.