# Assigning turtles a ranked number in netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I'm trying to assign turtles a number which I can tell them to move in order of. Using previous posts and some general playing around I've managed to create a ranked order list of the turtles, but now I want to assign turtles a number based on their relative position in that list.

Example:
current list: [(turtle 8) (turtle 1) (turtle 9) (turtle 0)]
desired turtle designation: turtle 8 = 1, turtle 1= 2, turtle 9 = 3, etc.

So far I've reached:

```
globals [rank_list]
turtles-own [var.
            rank]
set rank_list sort-on [var.] turtles

create-turtles (50)
 [setxy (random-float max-pxcor) (random-float max-pycor)
 set var. random-normal 0.5 0.175
  if var. > 1 [set sociability 0.99999999]
  if var. < 0 [set sociability 0.00000001]
foreach rank_list ask ? [set rank ...     ;this is where I get stumped 

to go 
ask turtles [foreach rank [ask ? [move]]]
end
```

any tips for assigning values based on the ranked order in a list would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Nicolas' answer above I've achieved the goal or ranked order movement. It's still a bit processing-power-intensive for the 2000 turtles I'm working with, but at least it runs!

```
turtles-own [var]

to ranking
let rank-list sort-on [var] turtles
let ranks n-values length rank-list [ ? ]
    (foreach rank-list ranks [ask ?1 [set var ?2] ] )
end

to make_turtles
    create-turtles (5)
    [set var random-normal 0.5 0.2
      set color scale-color blue var 0 1
      set size 3]
     ranking
     ask turtles [set label var]

     end

to move
 let rank-list sort-on [var] turtles
ask turtles [foreach rank-list [ask ? [ forward random 9]]]
end

to setup
  clear-all
  make_turtles

end
to go
  move
end
```

Comment: You are currently re-sorting your turtles at every tick. If you want to save processing power, store your rank list in a global variable.

Comment: I literally did that about 5 minutes before I saw this answer. You're right, works perfect now :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `n-values` to generate the ranks and the variadic version of `foreach` to loop through both the `rank-list` and the ranks at the same time:

```
turtles-own [ var rank ]

to setup
  clear-all
  create-turtles 50 [
    setxy random-pxcor random-pycor
    set var random-normal 0.5 0.175
  ]
  let rank-list sort-on [ var ] turtles
  let ranks n-values length rank-list [ ? ]
  (foreach rank-list ranks [ ask ?1 [ set rank ?2 ] ])
end
```

But the question is: do you really need a `rank` variable? Why not use the `rank-list` directly:

```
foreach rank-lisk [ ask ? [ move ] ]
```

Or even just sort your turtles on `var` each time:

```
foreach (sort-on [ var ] turtles) [ ask ? [ move ] ]
```

The latter is not the most efficient, but if you have only 50 turtles and do this only once per tick, you'll never notice the difference.

Comment: Thanks Nicolas. I'm working on incorporating your suggestions now. To your last point however, I need to be able to run with 2000 turtles and each turtle is engaging in a vary long decision process each tick so efficiency is key. I managed to find a way to do this originally, but I didn't have the processing power to run with the full population. I'm thinking the rank-list suggestion will work though, I'll update the code once I get it working.

Comment: I just noticed a flaw in the code below, which is based off your answer Nicolas. For some reason not only do the turtles move according to their rank, but they also move the same number of times as there are turtles in the world when I use an input box instead of providing an actual number. I'm completely stumped by this... any ideas?