# Make turtles move ONCE according to their ranked order in a list

Tags: netlogo

This question is built off my previous 2. I've been working to get a rank-ordered list for my turtles, ranked by an owned factor. They're then required to move in ranked order. That part works perfectly fine, and the code can be found at: [Assigning turtles a ranked number in netlogo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38250139/assigning-turtles-a-ranked-number-in-netlogo)

The problem: using that code, they're moving in the correct order but instead of moving once, the program seems to be continuously re-running it for every turtle in the list so the first turtle in a world of 10 ends up moving 10 times, the second moves 9 times, etc.

I'm completely stumped on this, but I need it to stop. They're supposed to move once and be done for that tick. Ideas?

The list creation code is:

```
let rank-list sort-on [sociability] turtles
    let ranks n-values length rank-list [ ? ]  
   (foreach rank-list ranks [ask ?1 [set social_rank ?2] ] ) 
;;you can replicate the problem with this movement proc, or the full code in the link above       
 ask turtles [foreach rank-list [ask ? [set heading 270 forward 1]]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the line:

```
ask turtles [foreach rank-list [ask ? [set heading 270 forward 1]]]
```

You're asking *each* turtle to execute a command *for each* turtle in your `rank-list`.

Just drop the `ask turtles` part.

As a more general note: `foreach` is to lists what `ask` is to agentsets. They both do the same basic thing, which is to perform a command for each item of a "collection". Agentsets are unordered collections of unique agents. Lists are ordered collections of possibly duplicated items of any type.